# Steps behind building a Pivot Table

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

I have a decent understanding of SQL (I think, anyway). Enough to form reasonable queries and get the data I want, albeit not always in the nicest format.

I have following query;

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2014-07-01'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2014-07-16'

SELECT Name, [Leave Type], SUM([Days Taken]) AS [Days Taken]
FROM(
    SELECT LR.idLeaveRequest, U.Name, LR.[start date], LR.[end date], SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, LR.[start date], LR.[end date])) + 1 AS [Days Taken],
    L.LeaveType AS [Leave Type]
    FROM LeaveRequests LR
    INNER JOIN Users U ON U.idUser = LR.id_User
    INNER JOIN Leave L ON L.idLeave = LR.id_LeaveType
    WHERE @StartDate <= CAST([start date] AS DATE) AND @EndDate >= CAST([end date] AS DATE) AND id_Status = 3
    GROUP BY LR.idLeaveRequest, U.Name, LR.[start date], LR.[end date], L.LeaveType) AS Original
GROUP BY [Leave Type], Name
```

Which gets the data out, but it's not really the nicest format as "Joe" might have 3 days of Annual Leave and 3 days of Leave in Lieu, which means two rows for Joe. Ideally, it would be 1 row and 2 columns.

I *think* I need to do a `PIVOT (MAX([Days Taken]) ON [Leave Type])` but I'm not quite sure if it's possible to dynamically get the columns from the LeaveType table? Also, I not 100% sure on the thought process that goes into building the pivot table and I think if someone could explain the best way to go about visualising/building the table when starting from scratch (or from where I'm currently at), I think it would go a long way towards me not needing to ask for help again.

(I can't use anything other than raw SQL as this will be going into a program that produces a nice report based on the results of the SQL query)

**Table Data**

```
LeaveRequests  
idLeaveRequest int PK  
start date     DATE  
end date       DATE  
id_Status      int  
id_LeaveType   int  
id_User        int  

Leave  
idLeave int PK  
LeaveType varchar

User  
idUser int PK  
Name varchar
```

**Current Output**

```
Name | Leave Type | Days Taken  
Joe  | RDO        | 5  
Joe  | Annual     | 2
```

**Desired Output**

```
Name | Annual | RDO  
Joe  | 2      | 5
```

Comment: Please put the create table statements for yor tables, sample rows and expected output. Then, it will be easy to help you.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Is that more help now?

Comment: Can you list all the possible types of leave as we need to explicitly define each column.

Answer (score 0):

Use following query in order to have dynamic pivot:

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(1000) = '',
        @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Columns = STUFF((SELECT ',['+[Leave Type]+']'
                        FROM(
                            SELECT DISTINCT L.LeaveType AS [Leave Type]
                            FROM LeaveRequests LR
                            INNER JOIN Users U ON U.idUser = LR.id_User
                            INNER JOIN Leave L ON L.idLeave = LR.id_LeaveType
                            WHERE @StartDate <= CAST([start date] AS DATE) AND @EndDate >= CAST([end date] AS DATE) AND id_Status = 3
                            ) AS Original                        
                        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')


SET @sql = 'DECLARE @StartDate DATE = ''2014-07-01''
            DECLARE @EndDate DATE = ''2014-07-16''

            SELECT * 
            FROM (
                SELECT Name, [Leave Type], SUM([Days Taken]) AS [Days Taken]
                FROM(
                    SELECT LR.idLeaveRequest, U.Name, LR.[start date], LR.[end date], SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, LR.[start date], LR.[end date])) + 1 AS [Days Taken],
                    L.LeaveType AS [Leave Type]
                    FROM LeaveRequests LR
                    INNER JOIN Users U ON U.idUser = LR.id_User
                    INNER JOIN Leave L ON L.idLeave = LR.id_LeaveType
                    WHERE @StartDate <= CAST([start date] AS DATE) AND @EndDate >= CAST([end date] AS DATE) AND id_Status = 3
                    GROUP BY LR.idLeaveRequest, U.Name, LR.[start date], LR.[end date], L.LeaveType) AS Original
                GROUP BY [Leave Type], Name)p
            PIVOT (MAX([Days Taken]) FOR [Leave Type] IN ('+@columns+')Pvt'

EXECUTE(@sql)
```

Comment: It gives the following error: Must declare the scalar variable "@StartDate".

Comment: @FizzBuzz.I change my answer. please check again.

Comment: Thanks. I should probably mention, this is run via a C# SqlDataAdapter & SqlCommand...It doesn't seem to like have the entire answer above placed into a string. Possible to fix? Or should I resign myself to making it static?

Answer (score 0):

The general form which is not dynamic is:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2014-07-01'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2014-07-16'

SELECT Name, 
SUM(CASE WHEN [Leave Type] = 'RDO' THEN [Days Taken] ELSE 0 END) AS RDO,
SUM(CASE WHEN [Leave Type] = 'Annual' THEN [Days Taken] ELSE 0 END) AS Annual
FROM(
SELECT LR.idLeaveRequest, U.Name, LR.[start date], LR.[end date], 
SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, LR.    [start date], LR.[end date])) + 1 AS [Days Taken],
L.LeaveType AS [Leave Type]
FROM LeaveRequests LR
INNER JOIN Users U ON U.idUser = LR.id_User
INNER JOIN Leave L ON L.idLeave = LR.id_LeaveType
WHERE @StartDate <= CAST([start date] AS DATE) AND 
@EndDate >= CAST([end date] AS DATE)     AND id_Status = 3
GROUP BY LR.idLeaveRequest, U.Name, LR.[start date], 
LR.[end date], L.LeaveType) AS Original
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: Is it possible to make dynamic? I don't need it to say 0, it can be null.

Comment: The other answer is the dynamic answer. Go with that.